# Python: The resulting array of type string does not match

Tags: python, technical-indicator

I want to make a program to group words consisting of the same characters in an array, but the results don't match when using the **Python** programming language

Example problem: Suppose I have 3 arrays of type string as follows:

```
oe1 = ["abc", "def"];
oe2 = ["asd", "cab", "fed", "eqw"];
oe3 = ["qwe", "efd", "bca"];
```

**Note**: The order of the array or the elements doesn't matter, the important thing is that they are grouped.

**Output example:**

```
[abc, cab, bca]
[asd]
[def, fed, efd]
[eqw, qwe]
```

But I try to use coding like this the results are not appropriate:

```
oe1 = ["abc", "def"];
oe2 = ["asd", "cab", "fed", "eqw"];
oe3 = ["qwe", "efd", "bca"];

anagram_list = []
for word_1 in oe1:
  for word_2 in oe2:
      for word_3 in oe3:
        if word_1 != word_2 != word_3 and (sorted(word_1)==sorted(word_2)==sorted(word_3)):
            anagram_list.append(word_1 + word_2 + word_3)
print(anagram_list)
```

my output is like this:

```
['abccabbca', 'deffedefd']
```

How do I make it match the example output above?

Comment: Nitpick: those are _lists_ and not arrays.

Answer (score 3):

First off, let's combine those lists and sort them using a lambda that converts each string to a list of characters, then sorts that.

```
>>> sorted(oe1 + oe2 + oe3, key=lambda s: sorted(list(s)))
['abc', 'cab', 'bca', 'asd', 'def', 'fed', 'efd', 'eqw', 'qwe']
```

Then using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group them based on the same lambda.

```
>>> k = lambda s: sorted(list(s))
>>> [list(v) for _, v in groupby(sorted(oe1 + oe2 + oe3, key=k), key=k)]
[['abc', 'cab', 'bca'], ['asd'], ['def', 'fed', 'efd'], ['eqw', 'qwe']]
```

This can be simplified a bit further by not first converting to a list and just sorting each string.

```
>>> sorted(oe1 + oe2 + oe3, key=sorted)
['abc', 'cab', 'bca', 'asd', 'def', 'fed', 'efd', 'eqw', 'qwe']
>>> [list(v) for _, v in groupby(sorted(oe1 + oe2 + oe3, key=sorted), key=sorted)]
[['abc', 'cab', 'bca'], ['asd'], ['def', 'fed', 'efd'], ['eqw', 'qwe']]
```

Answer (score 0):

To be easier, let merge them all together. Also, use condition with `set()` to check whether 2 text are using the same set of characters.

However, my solution doesn't require any `sort()`. But I added it because I want the output to be the same as your desired output.

```
oe = oe1 + oe2 + oe3
oe.sort() # optional, no need for sorting
oe_group = []
for i in range(len(oe)):
    if i == 0:
        oe_group.append([oe[i]])
    else:
        for j in range(len(oe_group)):
            if set(oe[i]) == set(oe_group[j][0]):
                oe_group[j].append(oe[i])
                break
            if j == len(oe_group) - 1:
                oe_group.append([oe[i]])
```

output

```
[['abc', 'bca', 'cab'], ['asd'], ['def', 'efd', 'fed'], ['eqw', 'qwe']]
```